# How to make an MD5 file on a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, checksum

I'm sending a source code package to someone via email. I have sent them an .svdump which contains the files. They have now asked me to send an MD5 file for the source dump. How do I create this on a Mac?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open up a **terminal** and invoke the `md5` program with the filename that you want to create a hash for:

```
md5 some_app > md5.txt
```

The command above stores the resulting hash in a file named `md5.txt`.

Comment: Wasn't me! However how can I create an MD5 file? I know how to create the MD5 string. Whats an MD5 file? Is it just a txt file with the MD5 string in it?

Comment: Exactly, and usually the filename of the md5 is the name of the target file followed by the `.md5`extension.

Answer (score 12):

In your terminal, just use the command "md5" and the file name. It's in /sbin/md5 i think.

```
> md5 -r myfile.txt
```

Comment: Apple's doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/md5.1.html